# Must a lightsaber be dropped down perfectly vertical for it to burrow down to Earth's core?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, solution-verification

[image]

In Season $6$ Episode $10$ of Rick and Morty, Morty drops a lightsaber down perfectly vertically. The lightsaber starts melting through the Earth, heading for the Earth's core. If the lightsaber hits the Earth's core, the Earth will be destroyed.

However, the core is quite big with a radius of $3485$ km. So, even if the angle the light saver was dropped was slightly off, it could still melt its way to the core.

For this situation, I will model the Earth as a circle with a radius of $6378$ km, and its core as a concentric circle with a radius of $3485$ km. The lightsaber will be a point that is traveling in a straight line. The lightsaber travels in a straight line because of the hard handle that is attached to it, which can't travel in a curved path. We get the following diagram with this info.
[image]
We want to see which angles will allow the lightsaber to reach the core, so I'll draw two tangent lines from the lightsaber to the core. I will also draw in the radius of the core, which will be perpendicular to the tangent line. Then, I will draw in the orange line, which is the radius of the Earth. This forms a right triangle I can use to solve for the angle theta.
[image]
sin(theta) = opposite/hypotenuse = $3485/6378$. Taking the arcsin. I get theta = $33$ degrees.
Thus, the lightsaber could've been dropped at an angle of $33$ degrees to the left/right and still have hit Earth's core.

Is this work correct? Any assumptions I have made (like modeling this system as two concentric circles) that could be incorrect?

Thanks

Comment: It's a well-known rule of lightsabers that they cut when the plot requires it, and don't cut when the plot requires that they don't. Evidently the plot requires that a lightsaber dropped at the wrong angle doesn't cut.

Comment: @DavidK Well, they never said that in the show that it HAD to be perfectly vertical. I think they were just impressed that it was dropped perfectly vertical

Comment: This is a math site, so I'll confine the physics to a comment: Here's at least one incorrect assumption. You seem to be assuming that the lightsaber will continue travelling in the direction in which it was travelling when dropped. Even if we assume that a lightsaber travels through rocks and magma alike without receiving the slightest momentum transfer, we know it's subject to gravity (since R2D2 can shoot it up in the air to let Luke catch it on its way down), so its trajectory is curved when it's not dropped vertically.

Comment: @joriki The lightsaber's motion is constrained by the nonmalleable hard handle attached to it. The handle can't travel in a curve, so the lightsaber can't. At least that's what I think

Comment: I'd imagine the light saber's electronics would be destroyed when the pressure becomes too great

Comment: I always thought the blade of the lightsaber, being projected from a port at the end of the hilt, was narrower than the hilt. Hence if you drop it straight down it should make a hole the width of the blade, then get stuck and stop falling when the hilt reaches the hole. But if we suppose the blade is the same or larger diameter than the hilt, we still have the issue that the hilt is irregular in shape and while well balanced, probably not so perfectly balanced that it will not bump against the sides of the hole and cause the blade to turn direction slightly, curving the shaft.

Comment: Just look at a picture of a lightsaber's hilt: it's not a perfectly smooth cylinder, far from it. So it **can** wobble inside a cylindrical hole.

Comment: If you drop a lightsaber at (say) a $10^\circ$ angle from vertical, gravity is still pulling it straight down so initially the blade will slice into the ground rather than drilling a hole. Then the hilt, whose upper end overhangs the blade as seen from below, will hit a part of the ground that the blade did not cut. The hilt cannot cut through the ground, so it bounces, and all kinds of chaotic interactions between hilt and hole can ensue, sending the blade in who knows what direction.

Comment: On the other hand physics is kind of irrelevant to Star Wars anyway, so you can make whatever rules you want. :-)

Comment: Unless you're dropping it from one of the poles, there's also the Coriolis force to consider, caused by the Earth's rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically, your assumption is accurate, but physically, it is not. Remember that the gravitational force pulls towards the center of an object, so since the direction of the force is not in the same direction as the trajectory of the lightsaber, the lightsaber will follow a nonlinear path rather than a straight line towards the center of the Earth.

I don't know much about Star Wars, but I'll take your word for it that the lightsaber will continue to travel in a straight line because of its handle. In this case, I assume that this force is not affectd by the gravitational force, so you are correct.